# Can i set state in parent from child using useEffect hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a set of buttons in a child component where when clicked set a corresponding state value true or false. I have a useEffect hook in this child component also with dependencies on all these state values so if a button is clicked, this hook then calls setFilter which is passed down as a prop from the parent...

```
const Filter = ({ setFilter }) => {

  const [cycling, setCycling] = useState(true);
  const [diy, setDiy] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilter({
      cycling: cycling,
      diy: diy
    });
  }, [cycling, diy]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Button block onClick={() => setCycling(!cycling)}>cycling</Button>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Button block onClick={() => setdIY(!DIY)}>DIY</Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

In the parent component I display a list of items. I have two effects in the parent, one which does an initial load of items and then one which fires whenever the filter is changed. I have removed most of the code for brevity but I think the ussue I am having boils down to the fact that on render of my ItemDashboard the filter is being called twice. How can I stop this happening or is there another way I should be looking at this.

```
const ItemDashboard = () => {

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('on mount');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('filter');
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <Container>..
      <Filter setFilter={setFilter} />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why don't you control all state variables in parent component ? And what is the main issue here ? Doesn't it update the parent's state with setFilter method ?

Comment: Yes it does update the parents state but the effect on the filter state fires twice on load and in my code the filter effects a load of items from a database twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing, you're looking for the way to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) to common parent.

In order to do that, you may bind event handlers of child components (passed as props) to desired callbacks within their common parent.

The following live-demo demonstrates the concept:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { useState } = React
      
const hobbies = ['cycling', 'DIY', 'hiking'] 

const ChildList = ({list}) => (
  <ul>
    {list.map((li,key) => <li {...{key}}>{li}</li>)}
  </ul>
)
      
const ChildFilter = ({onFilter, visibleLabels}) => (
  <div>
  {
    hobbies.map((hobby,key) => (
      <label {...{key}}>{hobby}
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          value={hobby}
          checked={visibleLabels.includes(hobby)}
          onChange={({target:{value,checked}}) => onFilter(value, checked)}
        />
      </label>))
  }
  </div>
)
      
const Parent = () => {
  const [visibleHobbies, setVisibleHobbies] = useState(hobbies),
        onChangeVisibility = (hobby,visible) => {
          !visible ?
          setVisibleHobbies(visibleHobbies.filter(h => h != hobby)) :
          setVisibleHobbies([...visibleHobbies, hobby])       
        }
   return (
      <div>
        <ChildList list={visibleHobbies} />
        <ChildFilter onFilter={onChangeVisibility} visibleLabels={visibleHobbies} />
      </div>
   )
}

render (
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, `useEffect` in child component which depends on the state is also how you typically implement a component which is controlled & uncontrolled:

```
const NOOP = () => {};

// Filter
const Child = ({ onChange = NOOP }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(counter);
  }, [counter, onChange]);

  const onClick = () => setCounter(c => c + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// ItemDashboard
const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, [value]);

  return <Child onChange={setState} />;
};
```

[image: Edit stoic-snow-snu7o]

Comment: this is essentially what I had already but thanks for the answer. I don't think I asked the right question so will ask another one.